# Movie about a boy with telekinetic powers

Tags: story-identification, telekinesis

I've been thinking about a movie which I saw as a kid in 80-90xx. Here are some scenes which I remember:

- A boy has uncontrolled telekinetic abilities and he is on the run from people (officials) who want to investigate it.
- His friend who plays a musical instrument (violin or smth else) helps him to train his abilities. Puts a glass/bottle/plate on a table and tells him to move it without dropping.
- In the end government officials ask him to handle a special bomb filled with liquid very high explosive material. The bomb was stuck on a ramp of some building. The boy successfully prevents explosive liquid from spilling out of the bomb and moves  it with his powers to the ground.
- In the last scene the boy helps to his musician friend to get a soloist party with an orchestra after demonstrating to a theater director his powers.

Appreciate to find out what was the movie title.

Answer (score 6):

It is ["The young magician"](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0092806/) (original Polish title "Cudowne dziecko"). 
[image][image]

> A 12-year boy feels left out by his classmates because he has no interest in athletics. He finally discovers his calling when his parents take him to a magic show. Picked by the magician to be his helper during a trick he is drawn into the world of magic and wants to learn more. He becomes proficient in tricks and also discovers his telekinetic powers. Unfortunately that further alienates him from his peers and his parents are afraid of his powers. Things change when a national emergency arises and the government asks him to help.

I've seen it as a kid myself :)  I remember the scene when he longingly looks through the window on his classmate's birthday party (that he wasn't invited to) and accidentally makes all soda cans to explode.

Here is the fragment with throwing flowers at his friend: