# 80s-90s thriller with a telekinesis wielder called to prevent a chemical from dripping off a hangar's ceiling

Tags: story-identification, movie, tv, telekinesis

In ~1990, ~1995 I saw a movie in TV, kind of thriller about a person with telekinetic abilities.

The only scene I remember is probably the final one, gripping, in huge hangar? Some chemical substantion slowly moving down from the ceiling, forming a drop that is about to fall and to cause some great disaster and this guy was called to prevent it with his telekinesis abilities, and he did it.

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! This question would be improved by going through the checklists here; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)

Comment: I think your answer is here already: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/93001/movie-about-a-boy-with-telekinetic-powers

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Movie about a boy with telekinetic powers](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/93001/movie-about-a-boy-with-telekinetic-powers)

Comment: Not a dupe unless both OP and the OP of the target post confirm their respective answers

Comment: Yes, this is the movie I was looking for.